# any ways to finish processing a codemagic build on app store connect testflight?

Tags: flutter, app-store-connect

I have used codemagic.io to build and send a flutter project to app store connect. It shows up fine in testflight but the app status never changes from processing... so i can not test the app.

Comment: How long has the app marked as "processing"?

Comment: 5 days now. i have uploaded a second version - it has the same problem...

Comment: Have you got any email from Apple?